# react router passed data is lost after refreshing th page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
"axios": "^0.20.0",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

i send data from a page to another and i have access to it until i refresh the page and then i get this error message:

```
error TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of undefined
```

i'm not setting the received data to state and use it through `this.props.location.data.phone`.
how can i solve this problem.

first page:

```
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: command,
    data: {phone: this.state.data.phone, choiceId: "1"},
  });
```

second page:

```
phone: this.props.location.data.phone
```

Comment: Route state is really transient, basically survives the journey of the route transition. You will need to persist this to something like localStorage and even react component state is generally reset after a page load.

Comment: pass through Query/Param, instead of data